# Is it Possible to create a relationship like this 1 to 0..1 + 0..1 to 1

Tags: c#, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

Want to create the same RelationShip between Student and Result as i've created between Subject and Result is it possible ?? to create a relations like 1 to 0..1 -0..1 to 1??

[image: Want to create the same RelationShip between Student and Result as i've created between Subject and Result is it possible ?? to create a relations like 1 to 0..1 -0..1 to 1??]

Edit: To explain question in more detail

Similarly like in this pic There is a 1 to 1 relationship between student and antecedence i want to create the same relationship between Studet and Family Data i.e 1 to 1 relation ship is it possible ??
[image]

Comment: How could a result not have a valid student?

Comment: Currently there exist a relation ship between result and student as many to 1 that is each result wil have a valid student so not sure what you are talking about.
But what I want to do is to create 1 to 1 relationship between Result and student like its between subject and results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add MS SQL physical 1 to 1 relationship as when adding objects you will have to add some object first. I'd suggest to add a student first, so I'd use foreign key from Results to Students just like the one you have. StudentID also should be NOT NULL to avoid lack of reference.

> create unique index IX_Results_StudentID on Results (StudentID);